# Counting occuriences from another table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table `teachers` (each teacher has got only one module, but module can have many teachers):

```
SELECT * from teachers;

ID | teachers| module_id | year
-------------------------------
Int| varchar | Int       | Int
-------------------------------
1  | Jack    | 12        | 2015
2  | John    | 56        | 2016
3  | Alex    | 12        | 2015
4  | Tony    | 56        | 2015
5  | Matt    | 56        | 2015
6  | Pete    | 12        | 2016
7  | Boby    | 14        | 2014
```

And so on...

And the table `modules`:

```
SELECT * from modules
module_id_| title    
--------------------
Int       | varchar    
--------------------
12        | Maths    
56        | PE       
14        | Biology
```

And I would like to have a query that give me a list of modules and how many teachers have them and in which year(and sort by this year). So the result would be

```
PE, 3, 2015, 2016 (in 2015 whas most)
Maths , 3, 2015, 2016
Biology , 1, 2014
```

EDIT:

Result of the answer below is this, and its not what I wanted:

```
 count | year | title
-----------------------
   1   | 2015 | Maths 
   1   | 2016 | PE 
   1   | 2015 | Maths 
   1   | 2015 | PE 
   1   | 2015 | PE 
   1   | 2016 | Maths 
   1   | 2014 | Biology
```

Comment: I would like to do it in postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be something like this:

```
SELECT title, count(*), array_agg(distinct year order by year)
FROM modules m
JOIN teachers t ON t.module_id = m.module_id_
GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: its wrong, it doesnt print years in one line, and it lists teachers instead of moules

Comment: Your output doesn't seem like output of the query above. Here is what I got: http://pastebin.com/raw/sWB3z542